# What will happen to the bounty offered if I delete my posts through which I've earned reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

#### What will happen to the bounty offered if I delete my posts through which I've earned reputation?

For example, currently I have a reputation of 400+ in the Workplace and let's say I start a bounty for 300 reputation on a question.

Now after offering that, I **delete my posts** (I've posted 2 answers and neither is accepted).
So the reputation I've earned is no longer available. Will this affect the bounty offered or will I be prevented from deleting those posts?

---

I have gone through this [page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work?rq=1) but didn't find something like this.

Comment: Side note: [This one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/160437/33983) is old enough to give you reputation even after deleting it. I think you'd simply end up with 1 reputation; you can't get any lower.

Comment: Thanks, I just gave that as an example. It may be possible that someone has posted only 1 post, earned rep from that and delete it after awarding bounty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shouldn't affect the bounty offered. The bounty amount is taken away from your reputation as soon as it is offered. Therefore, even if you get down to 1 reputation, you have already been 'billed' the bounty amount and the bounty should go ahead as planned.

I've had something similar before. I had 101 reputation from the association bonus, offered a bounty of 100. I got taken down to 1 reputation but the bounty was awarded as usual as I had already been 'billed' the bounty amount.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In that case, will the reputation get deducted as we earn points through new posts?

Comment: @Ak. [No](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287051/348196).