# Reversing and redownvoting to force reputation loss

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes, etiquette, undo

### Background

I am aware of the [reasons reputation has a floor of 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2621/), and I think that's just fine. Occasionally I will downvote a post whose OP has a reputation of 1. I'm OK with how the downvote will only affect the post's score and not the OP's reputation. For reasons I do not understand, some of the terrible posts which I downvote will later get an upvote. (These *feel* like [pity upvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93356/) to me.) Since the downvote [won't retroactively change the OP's rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/287053/), now they have a reputation of 11 but their single post (and it's usually a single post) is at e.g. +1/-3.

Occasionally I will come across the post again in the course of my normal site activity. If it hasn't been edited, then I can't reverse my vote. This is a little annoying but, in the grand scheme of things, small. If it *has* been edited (in which case I'm more likely to see it again, due to the bump) then I will typically undownvote and redownvote for the express purpose of making my vote "count". This is especially likely on [Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/), where people will often blindly add spoilers to answers without checking for quality.

The first time I did this was out of spite, but now I also worry about them getting out of the [new user restrictions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) (most notably, answering protected questions) just because of this bad post.

Of course, if I come across the post again but it's been improved, or someone has pointed out why it's fine after all, I'll usually reverse the downvote without redownvoting. Sometimes I'll even upvote.

I recently realized that maybe I was exploiting the system a little bit, so I guess the essence of this is...

### Question

Assuming this specific sequence of events has occurred:

- I downvote a poor post
- The post is edited (not by me)
- I naturally find the post again, and it's still bad

Is reversing and immediately redownvoting OK? Should I stop doing it?

Comment: “Is reversing and immediately redownvoting OK?” -Do you find the edited question helpful, if it’s unhelpful, downvote it

Comment: @Ramhound I'm not sure what you mean by that. Do you mean I should downvote the edited but still bad post? I'm asking specifically about the case where I've *already downvoted* the bad post, and I manipulate the tools available to me to get the OP's rep down by two.

Comment: It doesn’t matter. Your reversal doesn’t earn them reputation back since their reputation wasn’t adjusted with the original vote. If the contribution isn’t helpful then you should downvote it.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by just downvoting it. **I've already downvoted it. If I do nothing it will still be downvoted.** I'm going out of my way to downvote it again. I agree that it should be downvoted. I'm not sure if it's okay to pull strings which will end up affecting just their reputation.

Comment: @bobble, I don't see much point in decreasing their score in this situation (leaving aside a question of whether trying to decrease someone's score is beneficial or not) (especially comparing -2 for downvote against +10 for upvote). If they are eventually stuck with reputation 1, there is nothing to do. If they have reputation >1 but don't create bad posts later, I see no reason to care about this -2 reputation. And if they continue creating bad posts, you can downvote these posts (again, no reason to care about just -2 reputation).

Comment: I'm also not asking for *whether* I should do this. I'm asking for whether it's *OK* to do this is I want to.

Comment: @bobble - The downvote either way contributes to a question ban or answer ban. So the only thing your downvote would do is temporarily prevent them from gaining additional permissions based on reputation gates.

Comment: @bobble, IMO, it should be OK to do this since 1) its observable effects (including affecting the ability to answer protected posts) are negligible, as I outlined above, 2) you didn't violate any rules.

Comment: But does it actually make any difference? The order in which votes are cast shouldn't matter.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum it does, because users can't drop below 1, so if a new user's post is at +0/-2 then they still have 1 rep

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is reversing and immediately redownvoting OK?

Yes, this is perfectly OK, in my opinion, especially with very low-quality posts where sometimes the post would get suspicious, unexplainable upvotes.

This is my rationale:

- The system doesn't prevent you from retracting your vote as long as the post has been edited. It also doesn't prevent you from resubmitting your up-/down-votes.
- You're well within your right to use the tools that the system provides as you see fit as long as there's no abuse.
- I don't believe there's abuse in this case.

Answer (score 7):

I guess part of the question is 'how' punitive a downvote is supposed to be.  Assuming there's any reputation gain, it presumes the user has gotten rep for *good* answers and has presumably learnt their lesson. Taking the effort to downvote a bad *past* question seems a little mean if the user has *learnt* and is generally doing better. Negative reinforcement isn't our *only* goal/means to help users improve.

Changing your vote is supposed to reflect a change (in quality) of the post. Mechanically its fine, and shouldn't get you in trouble but it doesn't feel like the right thing to do.

Comment: *"seems a little mean if the user has learnt and is generally doing better"*. That's a fair point, although bobble specifically mentions the case where the edited question is still poor, but has (probably) received a "pity vote", so its score is now +1/-3. In that situation, the OP probably *hasn't* learned to do better.